# moved magento and contact email is not working

Tags: email, magento

I moved a magento system to a new server combining magento and sql all on the same VM.

Everything is more or less working other than the contact form will not send an email,

I get

Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later

When I try to send an email with the contact form.  As I know practically nothing about Magento, I am not sure where to look.  I have been in the Magento admin and I see the contact page and I can turn the contacts page on and off.  As I have moved this from another working system, I am not sure how Magento sends it's mails.  Is it using a sendmail, or something that I perhaps haven't started on the new VM?  I am guessing this should be a simple change somewhere I hope, but I have very little idea of where to look there are so many options.  Any help on where to look for mail sending parameters would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you send email from other methods on the server?

Comment: this is a very basic VPS VM system, I haven't really got any apps or anything else that would send email.  The sendmail daemon is not running - and I that seems to have been the problem.  I've installed and configured sendmail and all appears to be well.  Assuming that relaying is denied in the default configuration, but better check to be sure.